# Cisco ASA CX IPS Signature updates

Tags: cisco

First time using the ASA CX. I am trying to update the IPS signatures. I am unsure how to do this? I went onto the cisco website and downloaded, "IPS-sig-S844-req-E4.pkg". I tried uploading it under 'Administration > Upgrades' but from what I can tell is this is the place to upload CX packages, not signatures. I am sure there is an easy answer to this but google is failing me on this one. Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all resolved.

ASA CX has an automated update system in place. It requires current licences for the modules that you want updates for, and it needs access outbound on tcp/80 and tcp/443.

The ASA CX establishes a connection to Cisco's update server on port 80 which then responds with the update server node IP address and establishes a connection to that on port 443 which then updates the ASA CX.

Unfortunately Cisco couldn't give me a list of IP addresses that the ASA CX would connect to so I had to add in a blanket ASA CX to any on 80,443 ACL.